# VRAM SDL_Texture?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I got my game using `IMG_Load` into a `SDL_Surfase` variable called `buffer` and the

```
SDL_Texture *data_in_vram = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(render, bufer);
```

then `SDL_Fre`.

But I saw the memory usage in windows that `SDL_Texture` is allocating all the data in to my ram memory.

I have heard that `SDL_Surface` uses the ram and the `SDL_Texture` should use Vram.

How can I track my memory vram, and why do I see that `SDL_Texture` is using ram memory allocations?

Also I hope you could help me with some faster mode to load my scene images.

Comment: IIRC `SDL_Texture` keeps a buffer in RAM in addition to VRAM

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you aren't using the software renderer, and make sure you are freeing the surface after creating a texture from it.